# mysql push notice to node.js

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

i want to build a application which will use the tech of node.js, socket.IO and mysql and php
the application will include a admin system which using php and mysql
the application will also include a frontend pages which using html and node.js

im wondering is it possible the mysql auto send a notice to node.js server, then the server pull the msg to frontend?

i knew that, it is possible to send the msg from the admin system, but i just want the frontend side listen to the mysql server, any query update it will give a notice to frontend, instead of using admin system to push the msg to node.js and then to push to frontend

i knew mssql has the feature, but donno mysql hv too?

Comment: It's in the nature of a database to be passive. You ask - it answers

Answer (score 1):

On the first view it might look like a cool idea - you update the database, MySQL notifies a generator which then updates your apparently static, pre-generated HTML frontend files...

**But:**

Think about which part of your stack actually knows best about which data you pull into your different pages and when you have to trigger an update. The database doesn't and shouldn't.

Don't overcomplicate things just because you change the way your stack works :) your admin software is the right part of your stack to *trigger* re-caching or updating of output files. Then you have a clear responsibility chain:

- Admin: data and page management
- Database: data persistence layer
- Frontpage generation (usually done on demand in most cases, using php - but of course you can do this when and how ever you want :))
- output persistence ( caching or just simply writing a static file to disk )